# How to combine two columns conditionally based on a third

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a df with four columns, all with a shared time series index. I need to merge column1 and column2 into a new column4 conditionally based on column3. im new to python and jumped straight to a failed for loop as follows

```
for i in df.column3.index:
    if df.loc[i, "column1"] > 180:
        df.loc[i, "column4"] = df["column1"]
    elif df.loc[i, "column1"] < 180:
        df.loc[i, "column4"] = df["column2"]
```

I'm hoping someone can suggest a solution.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate every row for this — normally that would be the case.

In this case, you can use `where`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).

And try the following for your example:

`df['column3'] = df.column1.where(df.index > 180, df.column2)`